# ScrollBar do DatagriedView acompanhar os registros - C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Tenho um DataGriedView onde adiciono os meus itens. Quando ele chega em um determinado número de registros na grid, ele vai adicionando e não conseguimos ver o restante. Existe alguma maneira de deixar o ScrolBar dinâmico? 
Por exemplo, o ScrolBar descer acompanhando sempre o último registro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, existe.

Vamos supor que tem um método onde adiciona as linhas à `DataGridView` com nome `dataGridView1` (exemplo de adição de linha por código, sem `DataBind`):

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new[] { "Linha 1" });
```

Depois de adicionar a linha basta fazer o seguinte:

```
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.GetLastRow(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible);
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, era isso mesmo.